# Chosing a mail service on Debian, for a specific use

Tags: debian, exim, mta

I am trying to setup a mail service on a local Debian Buster/Sid.

This mail service should take input mails and direct them to these locations :
- if mail is for "myownlocaldomain", it must be delivered to a local mailbox user.
- elsewhere, the mail goes to our ISP smarthost, that delivers (or not) to destination.

So far, I use exim4 for this purpose. I have done this set up a long time ago and can not really remember how I did manage to make it work, but I did.

Users had trouble with this setup : when they make a typo in recipient address, they don't get immediate feedback.
The mail goes through exim4 and generates immediatly "Recipient address rejected: Domain not found" in the log, but it takes time to notify the sender.

I have tried to shorten the retry and failing timers of exim4, in /etc/exim4/conf.d/retry/30_exim4-config :

"*     *     F,10m,2m"

I expected to have a retry every 2 minutes, then after 10 minutes the mail would bounce.

I have also edited the other config file ( /etc/default/exim4) to set :
QUEUEINTERVAL='1m'

So far, I can not manage to produce the following result : trying a bit to send mail, for a little time, then fastly NOTIFY the sender if the mail can not be sent.

I expect the following behaviour when my server receives a mail from my local network:

- mail to joe@localdomain goes to /home/joe/Maildir,
- mail sent from joe@localdomain to jack@example.com is sent to jack@example.com, through ISP smarthost, with sender name rewritten to match our real mail address,
- Any other mail goes to the ISP smarthost,
- IN ANY OF THESE CASE, if the mail can not be delivered right now, the sender must be notified.

exim4 would be fine for me, but at this time I am too scared to *break* something that works so far, by trying to edit anything in /etc/exim4/conf.d.

Is there  a way to sort out config files (with "option = my_value" lines), from the script files (with .ifndef and variables and code inside), from /etc/exim4 ?

I would be ok to backup my whole /etc/exim4 directory and try to modify some of these 47 files, but it would be easier to know where to start.

At this point, would I better to start from scratch, maybe with another MTA (qmail ? postfix ?) ? Or is there some trick I didn't understand with exim4, that would make it easier to understand and debug ?

Edit : I ran dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config and switched to the single config file option.
There still are 47 files in /etc/exim4.
I am glad emacs keeps a $file~ backup of every $file it alters : I have been able to check for files ending in "~", within /etc/exim4/conf.d/.

That is how I spotted this modification I made in /etc/exim4/conf.d/main/90_exim4-config_log_selector :

"# uncomment this for debugging

MAIN_LOG_SELECTOR == MAIN_LOG_SELECTOR +all -subject -arguments"

This is an edit I made a long time ago. I remember now. Tt says "uncomment this for debugging".

So : I am a total idiot missing something obvious about exim4 on Debian, or else it is designed to have 47 scripts already written, that you must edit here or there to configure.

I found the "exim -bP" command that nicely prints out current config, but it doesn't now show me WHERE in the config files.

I just have to keep track of any change in a separate file (isn't that what config files exist for ?), and/or know exim4 AND Debian enough to instantly think "that is in /etc/exim4/conf.d/foobar/number_description".

At this point I just decided to switch to anything else than "exim4 on Debian". I am going to try qmail, in the hope Debian didn't break it yet.

Comment: Note that all these .ifdefs and macros are mostly Debian's packaging -- standard Exim4 configuration is just a single linear file.

Answer (score 0):

Edit : after checking dma and nullmailer, I saw they didn't allow incoming connexion (how do you even configure thunderbird to use such a service ?).

Now using opensmtpd. Looks like it is working. 
So far all my config can be read within one file, taking one screen without scrolling. That is what I needed.